# Force close on small screen android device while works well on other devices

Tags: android

I installed an app on Samsung galaxy small screen device and it worked perfect. But when I installed it on a motorola fire XT( screen size bit more smaller than the other) - the app force close and shut down . How can i resolve this issue. It is having xml file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"     android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:gravity="left"       android:layout_gravity="left"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="134dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="0dip" >




   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/clock_layout"
    android:layout_width="134dp"
    android:layout_height="192.0dip"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="6.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip" >


   <custom.analog.clock.AnalogClock1
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/clock"
    style="@style/clock"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip" />

   </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout   
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dip"
                android:layout_weight="1.25"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

     <!-- 1.25 -->

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/men"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="48.0dip" android:layout_marginTop="8.0dip"
         android:background="@drawable/btn_custom"
         android:clickable="true" />

        <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_marginTop="58.0dip"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TimeZone"  android:textStyle="bold"
  />

       <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginTop=" 6.0dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Digital Clock"
    android:maxLength="12"
    />

   <DigitalClock
    android:id="@+id/
    digitalClock1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DigitalClock"   android:textColor="#FFCC33" /> </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>






  <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <!--    <Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt"
   />    


   <Button
    android:id="@+id/calculate7"
    android:layout_width="280dip"
    android:layout_height="68dip"
    android:clickable="true"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gettime" />

 -->
  </LinearLayout>


   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but ther s no error in logcat

Answer (score 0):

we write supporting screens in `Androidmanifest.xml` like

```
<supports-screens 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

see this 
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html